# How to use two clipboards?

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard

I use Ubuntu 20.04. I have read that Linux uses two clipboards:

- copy/paste using a mouse context menu
- copy/paste using keys: ctrl + c/ctrl + v

Here is my example usage (actions are performed in the Firefox):

- select a text using mouse and select from the mouse context menu "copy"
- select a text using mouse and press ctrl + c
- paste the text using mouse context menu
- paste the text using keys ctrl + v

I get the same paste result - the text copied using the last copy operation. Shouldn't I get different paste results ? How does it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two buffers that store something that can be pasted. These are:

- Primary

  You copy by *selecting text*, nothing else, simply selecting. The selected text can then be pasted by pressing the middle button (the wheel, on most modern mice) of the mouse. No <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, no right click copy, no nothing. Just select and then middle-click to paste.
- Clipboard

  This is the one you will be familiar with from other operating systems. This is what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> copies and pastes. This is what right click -> copy and right click -> paste use.

Some useful links:

- [Arch Linux Clipboard documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Clipboard)
- [Free Desktop documentation on cut and paste in X](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt)
- [Old, but still relevant, article explaining the different copy/paste methods.](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html)

Comment: You can also paste by using `Shift` + `Insert` instead of clicking mouse wheel ;)

Comment: @FilipKubicz yes, but why would you want to do that? You already have your hand on the mouse to select, why would you move to the keyboard and use a two-key shortcut instead of simply middle clicking? But yes, sure, it is indeed another way.

Comment: I just added it here for completeness. But I happen to use it often, especially if I move around terminals/screens and decide to paste much later, when I no longer have the mouse in hand.

Comment: @FilipKubicz ah yes, fair enough, that makes sense.